# What is written on my Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, mjolnir

I have recently come into posession of Mjolnir

[image: Mjolnir with rune scribblings]

It has runes written on four sides, like in the picture, and these runes are mirrored (written symmetrical) on other four sides. I assume, that these runes translate to "Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor." But I would like to know:

1. Does this writing means anything?
2. If so, in what language it is written? (Is it real or something in-marvel-universe)

I've written these runes to the paper [image: runes on paper]

There four lines for "phrase" on every side. I am not sure, that I've written them right and not-mirrored, I was using [this image](http://viking-source.com/images/Anglo-Saxon-Runes.jpg) of runes to guide me.

Comment: "*He who wields this hammer commands the lightning and the storm,"* apparently.

Comment: https://echostains.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/viking-runes.jpg

Comment: @Richard How did you get it? I've tried to translate first line and got `wutharkgwhnij`. Also first symbol is absent in table you linked(translating, I assumed it is thurisaz).

Comment: Don't ask me. I didn't translate it, I just linked some links I found.

Comment: Look at the Old Turkic alphabet and Proto-Turkic language letters

Comment: "Whosoever holds this hammer, if they be not under 3 years of age, shall find it suitable"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is backward-written runic of a combination of sources. It is a mix of [Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_Futhark) and [Younger Futhark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Younger_Futhark), [Anglo Saxon runes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon_runes), and [the script from Ultima](http://ultima.wikia.com/wiki/Runic_Alphabet), if the 4th rune from the left, on the top row, is any indication. I believe it to be rubbish -- there's a lot of consonants, but only a handful of vowels.

The first two lines read:

w u th a r k g w h n i j 
h ia n i j m s s x/z l nj [the symbol for the sun here]

It also used a few Greek letters, which is... special... for a race supposedly older than us.

[image: Not Asgardian]

Looking at this over a year later, I realized it's literally a slightly stylized revision of the Elder Furthark alphabet on Wikipedia! It's meaningless!

[image: Furthark]

The order itself is the same as was described in the [Old English rune poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_rune_poem) that described the Old English names for the runes. This is due to Elder Futhark going out of vogue shortly after it started being simplified into Younger Futhark and Anglo Saxon Futhorc, coinciding with the heyday of Old English and possibly even being written during the rule of [Alfred the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_the_Great), who established libraries and schools to teach Old English to the populace.

Comment: “It also used a few Greek letters, which is... special... for a race supposedly older than us.” — Maybe the Greeks actually got the letters from them!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Greek script is based on Phoenecian, itself based on Egyptian heiroglyphs!

Comment: which was clearly inspired by Norse gods!

Comment: Who were really aliens!

Comment: Note that the absence of vowels is not necessarily indicative of nonsense: some runic writing did a sort of "omit vowels, except when you don't" thing. Unfortunately, that sort of writing can be *very* hard to decipher unless you already know what it says, and/or speak the language fluently. (Note that I'm not saying this particular hammer has anything other than gibberish on it; I'm just saying that vowel count isn't as definite an indication as it would be in, say, English.)

Comment: Great answer, shame the writing is absolute nonsense, what a wasted opportunity to have something interesting written there, lazy designer pricks :)

Answer (score -3):

The rune that looks like an up-pointing arrow is for *Tw*, a Thor-like god type. Pronounced *too*, I think. Possibly Welsh.

edit: @Aegon:  Wales *is* Anglo-Saxon.

The Norse and Welsh had common ancestors.

Comment: Definitely not Welsh. [That's Tiwaz, or Tyr symbol used by Anglo Saxons who are certainly not Welsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Anglosaxonrunes.svg).

Comment: But it does represent a god named Tyr.

Comment: [Welsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtic_Britons) and 
[Anglo-Saxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxons) are quite different. Although technically yes, if you go back far enough *everything* has a common ancestor.

Comment: That's like equating Anglo-Saxons with Persians and Indians because they are all supposed to have one common Proto-Indo-European ancestor.

Comment: Welsh language itself is Celtic while Anglo-Saxon/English is West-Germanic. Not to mention, this [research](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-wales-18489735) indicates Welsh people existed long before Anglo-Saxons ever landed in Britain